# Draw with brushes swift

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, cgcontext, cashapelayer

I'm making drawing app and now i can draw only simple lines (I'm using CAShapeLayers). How i can draw brush lines like on the photos below?

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLOzm.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/b26Di.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltlae.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVnYj.jpg

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: Well you can use PencilKit Or CanvasView for Drawing in iOS.